# Is it ever Halachically permissible to kill a murderer who poses no further danger without trial?

Tags: halacha, murder

Is the killing of a terrorist who murders a Jew and would eagerly murder more people Halachically permissible if such a person is unable to actually perform additional murders?

According to [a Haaretz article](http://www.haaretz.com/opinion/1.763096) (discussing the Azaria trial), a Jew isn't allowed to kill someone under such a scenario; however, it mentions that some Rabbis disagree. What is the argument of those who disagree?

I know that

> הבא להורגך השכם להורגו

explains that Halachically, one is justified in killing someone who will murder them. But I assume that mere intent without the physical possibility of performing the murder isn't enough. I also understand that there are provisions regarding war, but who is to determine if such a killing is in war? Furthermore, I understand that murderers must be allowed to stand trial. So, what kind of Halachic argument could they possibly make?

Comment: I want it clear to everyone that this question is not about the case of the Azaria trial, but rather the case specified in the question: killing a terrorist who murders a Jew and would eagerly murder more people but is unable to actually perform additional murders.

Comment: Note it's very possible no one holds the position you describe and that article is setting up a red herring (and using it to attack rabbis who supported Azaria for other reasons). If you could better source the existence of these positions that would strengthen your question.

Comment: I suppose its a long-shot, but could it be argued that Jews are perpetually in a war against those who seek their destruction (and act and encourage others to act upon such desires)?

Comment: Note that there's also a difference between an attempted murderer after the fact and a murderer after the fact.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I'm not sure what the difference is, but either way the question is clearly only about the latter case.

Comment: @DoubleAA Offhand, Goel Hadam.

Comment: @Salmononius2 That only applies to certain relatives. The question was clearly about the general case